# Unable to press and hold on pop menu using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, jupyter

[image]

I am getting trouble while shifting from the previous window to pop window and then pressing this press and hold button as we cannot able to get the id or class because it's dynamically changing. Is there any solution to get rid of this pop menu by long **press and hold** using selenium lib?

````
 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(.,'Press and Hold')]//preceding::input[1]")))
#     element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/p")
    print("backing ot forward....")
    
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.click_and_hold(element)
    action.perform()
    time.sleep(10)
    action.release(element)
    action.perform()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    action.release(element)
    ```
Above are the lines of code that I am trying to run but due to dynamic id, it doesn't work well.
````

Comment: Try to include a minimal reproducible example including code, html element of code you want to press and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you may try. I had a similar issue. This worked for me.

The key is the release after 10 seconds (the timing might be different for your use case) and clicks again

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#id-captcha') # captcha id
action = ActionChains(driver)
click = ActionChains(driver)
action.click_and_hold(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(10) # change it as required
action.release(element)
action.perform()
time.sleep(0.2)
action.release(element)
```

Comment: The id  for captcha is changing every time when this captcha pops up. How to get that id actually?

Comment: Then select the captcha with different element

Comment: Actually captcha have only two elements id and class, both are changing randomly each time when captcha pops up .

Comment: how about their parent element/tag? the tag where it pops-up then you can wait and try with XPath as well

Comment: I tried with full XPath, but it doesn't even work with that. Apart from that parent div doesn't seems like working in my case.

Comment: is it an iframe? then switch to it

Comment: no inside a div there is button you can say .